# I think it's a Python MySQL error, but I can't understand the situation. [ERROR] InternalError: Unread result found

Tags: python, mysql, flask, lambda

This is my Flask API code

```
from flask import request
from flask_restful import Resource
from mysql.connector import Error
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, get_jwt_identity

from mysql_connection import get_connection

class OrderListResource(Resource):

    # 내 주문내역 조회 API
    @jwt_required()
    def get(self):

        userId = get_jwt_identity()
        offset = request.args.get('offset')
        limit = request.args.get('limit')

         # 기본값
        if not offset:
            offset = 0
        if not limit:
            limit = 20

        try:
            connection = get_connection()
            # 주문한 시간이 늦은 순으로 정렬
            query = '''
                    select *
                    from orders
                    where userId = %s
                    order by createdAt desc;
                    limit '''+offset+''', '''+limit+''';
                    '''
            record = (userId, )
            cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True, buffered=True)
            cursor.execute(query, record)
            result_list = cursor.fetchall()

            for row in result_list:
                row['reservTime'] = row['reservTime'].isoformat()
                row['createdAt'] = row['createdAt'].isoformat()
            
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
        
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            return {'error' : str(e)}, 500

        return {'result' : 'success',
                'items' : result_list,
                'count' : len(result_list)}, 200
```

I deployed this with AWS lambda and tested it with Postman.
It works normally in the local state, but "Internal Server Error" occurs in the server.
[Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rS7Z.jpg)
[AWS lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm7gL.jpg)

So I looked at the CloudWatch logs and got the following error message:

```
[ERROR] InternalError: Unread result found
```

Strangely, of all the APIs I have deployed, only this API is giving me an error.
Other APIs work fine both local and on the server.
So I don't know what's the problem.

I put bufferd=True in cursor(), which is a solution when searching for an "Unread result found" error, but it has no effect.

Comment: Side note - you should put `cursor.close()` and `connection.close()` in a `finally` block rather than write it out twice.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! The cause is that ; is used twice in the query. It's a simple problem, but it worked normally in the local state, so I couldn't find the cause. I'm sorry.